# Why does my static member function suppress the existence of a file-level static variable somewhere else?

Tags: c++, static, linker

I have a type

```
struct J : ::std::enable_shared_from_this<J> {
  static ::std::weak_ptr<J>& r() {
    static ::std::weak_ptr<J> _r;
    return _r;
  }
  J() {
    r() = shared_from_this();
  }
};
```

which basically provides some logging. However, when I enable the static function `r()`, somewhere else in the program a static variable:

```
// .cpp
namespace {
  llvm::cl::opt<bool> var("var");
}
```

somehow breaks, in the sense that it is as if it was commented out. No error is produced, as `var` is never referred to by name, but merely is supposed to add a command line switch (which words without `J::r` being linked).

What could possibly be the reason for this? I have tried to reduce the example to a minimum, but cannot produce an MWE.

Comment: *How* does your program "breaks"? Do you get build errors? Then at least ell us the errors you get, and where you get them.

Comment: Writing `::` before `std` strikes me is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Calling `shared_from_this` will fail (throw an exception) unless a `std::shared_ptr<J>` already exists.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: @NO_NAME: `namespace Mine { namespace std { /*Some stuff*/ } }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I did state how it breaks: " in the sense that it is as if it was commented out. No error is produced, as var is never referred to by name, but merely is supposed to add a command line switch (which words without J::r being linked)."

Comment: @Jarod42 Well yeah, you could do that if you really want to make your life harder. Although, it is better idea to not name anything std by convention.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, `J` is constructed as a `shared_ptr<J>` elsewhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The error I get is basically when invoking the built program, as `./a.out --var` does not recognise `var`. This happens only when including `J`.

Comment: This looks like a question that really needs an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you even sure that this particular lines are the cause of the problem? It can be elsewhere and be just triggered here.

Comment: `"J is constructed as a shared_ptr<J> elsewhere"` But how?  The `J` ctor calls `shared_from_this` and will, therefore, always fail.

Comment: It was the `shared_from_this`. I always forget that it's not allowed from the constructor. Removing smart pointers fixes the problem, but doesn't explain why it appeared.

Answer (score 1):

`shared_from_this` can only be called when `this` is already managed by another `std::shared_ptr`. Since you call it from `J`'s constructor, we can check this can not be the case.

From [`shared_from_this`'s page on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this):

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr`. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17) `std::bad_weak_ptr` is thrown (by the `shared_ptr` constructor from a default-constructed `weak_this`) (since C++17).

Since C++17, your code would break more clearly.

#### Code

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct J : std::enable_shared_from_this<J>
{
    J() {
        std::ignore = shared_from_this();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ignore = std::make_shared<J>();
}
```

#### Compile & run

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -O3 main.cpp && ./a.out
```

#### Output

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
bash: line 7: 28216 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

---

Before C++17, your code had undefined behavior. I can only guess this manifests itself by random/strange behavior.

I bet you want something more simple:

```
#include <memory>

struct J
{
    static std::weak_ptr<J> r() { return _auto_manager; }
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<J> _auto_manager;
};
std::shared_ptr<J> J::_auto_manager = std::make_shared<J>();


int main()
{
    auto p = J::r();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Do you have any explanation for why the linker would shadow another variable?
 [ My  problem is fixed, thank you, but I'm just curious. ]

Comment: @bitmask Undefined Behavior is undefined. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct J {
  static J*& r() {
    static J* _r;
    return _r;
  }
  J() {
    r() = this;
  }
};
```

fixes the problem as using `shared_from_this` in the ctor is wrong. But why the linker just omits `var` is unclear. The program should break when run, but should compile and link.